# Writing more than 1000 rows with arcpy.da.InsertCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geojson, cursor, limitations

I have a GeoJSON which I'm able to successfully covert to a shapefile via the following process: using `arcpy.asShape` to find geometry, and inserting this geometry as new fields using cursor insertRow).  Here's my code:

```
jData2 = json.loads(fp.read().decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8"))
for feature in jData['features']:
    #print feature['geometry']['type']
    point = feature["geometry"]
    geom = arcpy.AsShape(point, False)
   # print(geom.type)

  print("geometry read in!")

arcpy.env.workspace = bikeFacilitiesFolder = 'G:\Bike Facilities Data\SF_BikeLanes.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#make new fc
fc = r'G:\Bike Facilities Data\SF_BikeLanes.gdb\geojson_test'
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) 
path, name = os.path.split(fc)
arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(path, name, 'POLYLINE', spatial_reference=sr)
print("fc created!")

# add fields as listed from the properties of each feature
fields = ['street_', 'from_st', 'to_st', 'greenwave']
for field in fields:
    arcpy.management.AddField(fc, field, 'TEXT')
print("fields added!")

# insert rows
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@'] + fields) as irows:
    for feature in jData2['features']:
        geom = arcpy.AsShape(feature['geometry'], False)
        irows.insertRow([geom] + [feature['properties'][f] for f in fields])
```

For what it's worth, the original GeoJSON looks like this, and there's well over 1000 records:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.47512772300517,37.807408484936566],[-122.474966524051,37.80752154192644],[-122.47479521215574,37.80761005526742],[-122.47467695769082,37.807639745767275],[-122.47457098118358,37.80763960394547],[-122.47447242920829,37.807612594076865],[-122.47424339925378,37.80746166157941],[-122.47388562809269,37.807129457884606]]},"properties":{"number_":"95","from_st":"UNNAMED 078","contraflow":false,"greenwave":false,"barrier":null,"street_":"Unnamed077","sharrow":"0","cnn":"19789000","surface_tr":null,"globalid":"{1F9327AD-E680-42CD-8548-9D27BC06067F}","direct":"2W","double":"1","facility_t":"CLASS III","symbology":"BIKE ROUTE","fy":"0","sm_sweeper":false,"dir":"S","streetname":null,"buffered":false,"install_yr":null,"raised":false,"install_mo":null,"update_mo":null,"biap":false,"length":"0.09","notes":"PRESIDIO","qtr":"0","to_st":"UNNAMED 052","update_yr":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.47512772300517,37.807408484936566],[-122.474966524051,37.80752154192644],[-122.47479521215574,37.80761005526742],[-122.47467695769082,37.807639745767275],[-122.47457098118358,37.80763960394547],[-122.47447242920829,37.807612594076865],[-122.47424339925378,37.80746166157941],[-122.47388562809269,37.807129457884606]]},"properties":{"number_":"65","from_st":"UNNAMED 078","contraflow":false,"greenwave":false,"barrier":null,"street_":"Unnamed077","sharrow":"0","cnn":"19789000","surface_tr":null,"globalid":"{0A792A5B-B61F-408C-BD80-14F4CFB44A59}","direct":"2W","double":"0","facility_t":"CLASS III","symbology":"BIKE ROUTE","fy":"0","sm_sweeper":false,"dir":"N","streetname":null,"buffered":false,"install_yr":null,"raised":false,"install_mo":null,"update_mo":null,"biap":false,"length":"0.09","notes":"PRESIDIO","qtr":"0","to_st":"UNNAMED 052","update_yr":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.47602066615799,37.80689435429642],[-122.47538893345842,37.80633679782139]]},"properties":{"number_":"2","from_st":null,"contraflow":false,"greenwave":false,"barrier":null,"street_":"Hwy 101","sharrow":"0","cnn":"19866002","surface_tr":null,"globalid":"{3B269E34-F62F-4E21-AAA9-C9538221EDD6}","direct":"2W","double":"0","facility_t":"CLASS III","symbology":"BIKE ROUTE","fy":"0","sm_sweeper":false,"dir":"S","streetname":null,"buffered":false,"install_yr":null,"raised":false,"install_mo":null,"update_mo":null,"biap":false,"length":"0.05","notes":"PRESIDIO","qtr":"0","to_st":null,"update_yr":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.47388562809269,37.807129457884606],[-122.47343461065218,37.80672429719383]]},"properties":{"number_":"95","from_st":"LINCOLN BLVD","contraflow":false,"greenwave":false,"barrier":null,"street_":"Unnamed 077","sharrow":"0","cnn":"19790000","surface_tr":null,"globalid":"{EC671D49-B9DF-4832-86A4-5AAA4346A3A9}","direct":"2W","double":"1","facility_t":"CLASS III","symbology":"BIKE ROUTE","fy":"0","sm_sweeper":false,"dir":"S","streetname":null,"buffered":false,"install_yr":null,"raised":false,"install_mo":null,"update_mo":null,"biap":false,"length":"0.04","notes":"PRESIDIO","qtr":"0","to_st":"UNNAMED 078","update_yr":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.47388562809269,37.807129457884606],[-122.47343461065218,37.80672429719383]]},"properties":{"number_":"65","from_st":"LINCOLN BLVD","contraflow":false,"greenwave":false,"barrier":null,"street_":"Unnamed077","sharrow":"0","cnn":"19790000","surface_tr":null,"globalid":"{D84DFADC-2269-457F-B0C2-FA1C2C565777}","direct":"2W","double":"0","facility_t":"CLASS III","symbology":"BIKE ROUTE","fy":"0","sm_sweeper":false,"dir":"N","streetname":null,"buffered":false,"install_yr":null,"raised":false,"install_mo":null,"update_mo":null,"biap":false,"length":"0.04","notes":"PRESIDIO","qtr":"0","to_st":"UNNAMED 078","update_yr":null}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.47602066615799,37.80689435429642],[-122.47538893345842,37.80633679782139]]},"properties":
```

This code successfully writes geojson_test and I can open it in ArcMap, but it only has 1000 records.  It seems like there's a limit to the amount of rows I can write to a feature class.

Is there a way to get around this, especially, a way that doesn't involve a bunch of added code?

Comment: My personal record is 126 million rows added to a file geodatabase feature class in an InsertCursor stream; there certainly isn't a 1000 row limit, though queries only grab the first thousand at first when reviewing the table contents.

Comment: What does `arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)` return?

Comment: arcpy.GetCount_management(fc) prints out 1000, so not sure what's up here.  Am I for sure using a geodatabase feature class here?  It seems as if I am.

Comment: Or may be there is some sort of syntax corruption at the 1000 element in your geojson file terminating the insert cursor early?

Comment: That seems very unlikely.  It's almost certainly an issue with not being able to write more than 1000 rows.  This problem is documented in the past, though I'm having trouble finding a solution based on past answers: https://community.esri.com/thread/169204

Comment: But, thank you for your response!  The help is appreciated.

Comment: I realized my issue! I may go back and create another question.  The problem is, when I go here:  https://data.sfgov.org/Transportation/Bicycle-Parking/hn4j-6fx5  I'm clicking on API, and then GeoJSON.  The resulting text is only 1000 records (incomplete).  I can only access the entire GeoJSON if I go to "Export" and download as a geojson.  I get a complete shapefile doing the script above with the downloaded geojson.  Is this issue typical?  The way I'd like it to work is get the entire geojson hosted from a url.  Is this possible?

Comment: Given the volume, 1000 features is a customary feature limit on a steam feature service (though this is usually configurable on the part of the service administrator). Retrieving more than that, as a series of pages quries, may violate the terms of service of the provider.

Comment: When using the Export geojson, I get `arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)` == `Out[3]: <Result '5183'>`

Comment: I think I'm going to post this as a new question because the issue is more about feature limit in this case, rather than an issue with insertCursor.  To clarify: I can download a full geojson with all 5,183 records, but I can't pull the same geojson from a web link?  Is there any way around this?  My code relies on having a url where the geojson resides, but I need this geojson to have all records.  Thanks.